System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported. Path: $.HttpContext.Features.Key
I'm in a learning project, and at the moment of testing the endpoints, I have the following error:
System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported. Path: $.HttpContext.Features.Key.
This error occurs specifically in an endpoint called ListSelectCategories(), this endpoint does not receives any data from client:
[HttpGet("Select")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListSelectCategories()
{
    var response = await _categoryApplication.ListSelectCategories();
    return Ok(Response);
}

ListSelectCategories() method have the following code:
public async Task<BaseResponse<IEnumerable<CategorySelectResponseDto>>> ListSelectCategories()
{
    var response = new BaseResponse<IEnumerable<CategorySelectResponseDto>>();
    var categories = await _unitOfWork.Category.ListSelectCategories();

    if (categories is not null)
    {
        response.IsSuccess = true;
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategorySelectResponseDto>>(categories);
        response.Message = ReplyMessage.MESSAGE_QUERY;
    } else
    {
        response.IsSuccess = false;
        response.Message = ReplyMessage.MESSAGE_QUERY_EMPTY;
    }

    return response;
}

I will show you the CategoryResponseDTO:
namespace POS.Application.Dtos.Response
{
    public class CategorySelectResponseDto
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}

The application comunicates perfectly with the database, but, the error occurs at the moment of executing the "Ok(response)" method at the Controller. Cannot figure out what is causing the "serialization" because when I debug the code, the "response" variable seems perfect. I will add a picture of the response variable just before executing 'Ok' method

I hope you can help me with this, I've been stuck for 3 days and I don't know what to do! If you need this project to be uploaded to git for you to check it out, I will do it. Thanks :)

Change this line
    response.Data = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategorySelectResponseDto>>(categories);

to
    response.Data = categories;

Here is my test code and test result

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CategoriesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CategoriesController> _logger;
        private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
        public CategoriesController(ILogger<CategoriesController> logger, ICategoryService categoryService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _categoryService = categoryService;

        }
        [HttpGet("Select")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListSelectCategories()
        {
            var response = await ListSelectCategories1();
            return Ok(response);
        }
        private async Task<BaseResponse<IEnumerable<CategorySelectResponseDto>>> ListSelectCategories1()
        {
            var response = new BaseResponse<IEnumerable<CategorySelectResponseDto>>();
            var categories = new List<CategorySelectResponseDto>
        {
            new CategorySelectResponseDto { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Beverages" },
            new CategorySelectResponseDto { CategoryId = 2, Name = "Bakery" }
        };

            if (categories is not null)
            {
                response.IsSuccess = true;
                response.Data = categories;
                response.Message = "Data fetched successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                response.IsSuccess = false;
                response.Message = "Data fetched failed";
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}


I tried your suggestion, and I still have the issue, same error. What can I do?

@josmanuel Please create a minimal sample repo without any sensitive information for me, I will check it tomorrow.
